# Layout problem with ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

Hi all I'm trying to write a XML code that will allow me to obtain something similar to this:
[image]

The relative layout with buttons is a menu with 3 buttons, the problem is that right now the green ListView goes under the buttons (to the bottom of the screen), this is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundapp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_big"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_events"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CAMERA"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth_connect"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONNECT"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SETTINGS"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem inserting a transparent ImageView under the buttons:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/place_holder"
    android:src="@drawable/place_holder_transparent_55"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>
```

Thank you guys any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in the linear layout and set their widths to all be "fill parent." Right now you have the linear layout inide the relative layout. The liner layout should be set to arrange everything vertically and then place those sub views into the linear layout in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:layout_below="@id/ll"
```

to your `RelativeLayout` of buttons

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_above="@+id/rel_top"` property for the `LinearLayout` which is containing your `ListView`